# transform date macro variable to be used to create dynamic dataset name

Tags: sas

I am using this code:

```
LibraryName.Bla_&SomeDate._&AnotherDate.;
```

to create a dynamic dataset name. The code produces for example:

```
LibraryName.Bla_2016-10-29_2016-11-12
```

which SAS does not like. What can I do to fix this? I guess this would be a valid name:

```
LibraryName.Bla_2016_10_29_2016_11_12
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is named literal:

```
LibraryName."Bla_&SomeDate._&AnotherDate."n;
```

That should allow you to use it.  May or may not be a good *idea*, but it's possible.

If you prefer to use normal SAS names, you can process it in a `%sysfunc` call.  If you only ever have `-` and you want them to be `_` that's easy:

```
%let somedate=2016-10-29;
%let anotherdate=2016-11-12;
%let datasetvar = %sysfunc(translate(Bla_&somedate._&anotherdate.,_,-));
%put &=datasetvar.;
```

If you have other characters it could be more complex, depending on the situation; you could use the sas function `nvalid` to see if it would be a legal variable name (which is also more or less the same set of rules as for dataset, or 'member', names) for example.

Comment: As a sidebar, this sort of thing is not uncommon, and if you look around you can find code by various people to do much more complex versions of this; particularly look at the various folks who published utility macro libraries as this sort of thing would be a component of many of them.

Comment: Thanks. I google a bit but can you please be so kind and point me to good  utility macro libraries? Thanks!